I'm generating a Word document using Excel VBA and would like to switch into a bulleted list for a few lines at the selection
I'm generating a Word report based on data from an Excel sheet and I want to "turn on" bullet points for a few lines in the same way you'd "turn on" or "turn off" bold mode by clicking the button in the ribbon. I was hoping that since you can do .Font.Bold = True I would be able to do something similar for a bulleted list, but I couldn't find anything while searching the documentation or Googling the issue.
I tried to record a macro in Word to see if there was anything salvageable, but as expected, I got a mess:
Sub testBullet()

With ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(1)
        .NumberFormat = ChrW(61623)
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleBullet
        .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 0
        .StartAt = 1
        With .Font
            .Bold = wdUndefined
            .Italic = wdUndefined
            .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Subscript = wdUndefined
            .Superscript = wdUndefined
            .Shadow = wdUndefined
            .Outline = wdUndefined
            .Emboss = wdUndefined
            .Engrave = wdUndefined
            .AllCaps = wdUndefined
            .Hidden = wdUndefined
            .Underline = wdUndefined
            .Color = wdUndefined
            .Size = wdUndefined
            .Animation = wdUndefined
            .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Name = "Symbol"
        End With
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With
    ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(1).Name = ""
    Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
        ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(1), ContinuePreviousList:= _
        False, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, DefaultListBehavior:= _
        wdWord10ListBehavior
    Selection.TypeText Text:="Now I'm typing bulleted text"
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    Selection.TypeText Text:="time to leave"
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    Selection.Range.ListFormat.RemoveNumbers NumberType:=wdNumberParagraph
    Selection.TypeText Text:="no longer bulleted"
    Selection.TypeParagraph
End Sub

I had to put
Dim objWord As Object

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

at the start of my document, to make a lot of the word commands even work, so I already knew the recorded junk wasn't going to work because there are things that would need to be prefixed with objWord. like I had to do to refer to ActiveDocument, for example, and I also know I'll have to go to the enumeration table in the documentation and replace some names with numbers (for example, I've been using ColorIndex = 6 instead of wdRed), but I don't know what all in the recorded macro even needs to stay in the first place, much less what comes from Word's library specifically.
What can be safely cut out of the recorded macro and what's actually important? Better yet, is there a "switch on/off" way to apply bullet points like I apply font formatting? I know it would be relatively simple to apply the formatting to a range of text using something like this:
Make selected text in Word document bulleted (recording doesn't work)
But the document's section lengths are going to vary a lot based on the input from the Excel sheet, and if it's possible, I'd really like to avoid figuring out the logic of selecting the appropriate range if there's a way to do it as if the macro was just a person writing text from the top of the document to the bottom.

Recording macro is just a start point of coding.  Understanding the distinction between late and early binding is crucial when attempting to utilize Excel VBA code to manipulate Word.
Late Binding
What's the appropriate range?

There is a worked example (Example 6)  in this blog https://itpscan.ca/blog/excel/VBA-write-to-word.php#example_6

@taller by appropriate range, I meant a couple of lists whose lengths and positions in the paragraph structure are going to vary depending on the excel sheet, meaning I can't just throw in a procedure at the end that magically finds all the stuff that needs bulleted. I'm sure it's not really that bad to define a selection range relative to the current cursor position by just counting backward a number of lines equal to the number of items, I just haven't crossed that kind of bridge yet and hoped there was a cheesy workaround analogous to a Word user clicking the bullet point button.

and for anyone else reading, @CHill60 's answer worked

@truck - for future questions (or if you find an comment that helps you) the small up-arrow next to a comment can be used to indicate to others that the comment was useful. I'm glad you got this sorted

Quite why you have to make things so complicated is beyond me. Just apply the style “List Bullet”.

@CHill60 I tried, my account is apparently too new. I think you have to have ten rep first?

@TimothyRylatt In part I'm still just struggling with objects and methods in general, this is my third day using vba and I don't really program. At the time of writing I was also having difficulty getting styles to behave, which turned out to be due to something else, but even if they had been working, it seemed unwieldy to me to define styles for ~15-20 different kinds of text (some of which only get used once or for a few sentences) than to just leave all but my headings as generic body text and switch the 2 or 3 properties I need when I'm about to type the next bit of text.

@TimothyRylatt maybe I'm misunderstanding or not thinking the right way about this, but in my mind the number of times you intend to use a given style has an equilibrium point above which you would save time by enumerating every aspect of it in the header of the code, and below which it's no faster or slower to just define it in situ next to the text in question? By the same token I wouldn't think to bother defining a small function in a program unless I intended to call it more than once, (except for the sake of modularity, anyway), but again, that's maybe my lack of experience speaking.

Timothy is correct. Apply a style instead of using VBA to do a pile of redundant local formatting.

“List Bullet” is a built-in style based on the “Normal” style and, as its name suggests, is already defined with a bullet. So there isn’t any need to define a style, just apply one. Additionally your starting point for your report should be a Word template that already has all the styles in that your report would require, along with any standard text or structure, thereby requiring much less code.

“Better yet, is there a "switch on/off" way to apply bullet points like I apply font formatting?” - yes, that’s what the built-in ‘List Bullet’ styles are for.
